# Why does UIView animation change View frame?

Tags: swift, uiview

**UPDATE**: I added an explicit call to set the frame of the "to" view in the completion handler for the transition. **This solves the "problem" but does not answer the question about WHY the frame changes on hide.** Here is the new animation call. NOTE - I cleaned up the code a little by making a function for handling the spanSuperView() and animations, so this does not exactly match the original code. Gist is updated. I hope it helps someone, and perhaps someone else knows WHY.

This is the animation that works for multiple times:

```
func animateView(_ new: UIView) {
    UIView.transition(from: self.currentView, to: new, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: { finished in
            new.spanSuperView()
            new.isHidden = false
            self.currentView.isHidden = true
            self.currentView = new
            self.container.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

The animation is now called in the button switch method rather than repeated:

```
@objc func viewChange(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.tag)
        switch sender.tag {
        case 1 :
            print("should look at view1")
            print(currentView)
            animateView(viewone)
        case 2 :
            print(currentView)
            animateView(viewtwo)
        case 3 :
            print(currentView)
            animateView(viewthree)
        case 4 :
            print(currentView)
            animateView(viewfour)
        default:
            animateView(viewone)
        }
    }
```

Here is spanSuperView():

```
extension UIView {
    func spanSuperView() {
        guard superview != nil else { return }
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**
If there is no UIView.transition (just show | hide), the issue does not come up at all:

```
func animateView(_ new: UIView) {
        if new == currentView { return }
        new.spanSuperView()
        new.isHidden = false
        self.currentView.isHidden = true
        self.currentView = new
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
I'm trying to create a view with animated subviews, where the user can switch between them by clicking a button.
This works fine the first time that the view is shown, but the frame for the subviews changes after the first time, and then the view is animated without the subviews.

Here is the code for the playground. I also created a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/monkeywithacupcake/b4a90f6bb6662637d7d4295aede94318)

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class ButtonRow: UIView {
    var button1 = UIButton()
    var button2 = UIButton()
    var button3 = UIButton()
    var button4 = UIButton()
    var stackView = UIStackView()

    func updateButtonLabels(_ texts:[String]? = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]) {
        guard let texts = texts else { return }
        let buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4]
        var i = 0
        for btn in buttons {
            btn.setTitle(texts[i], for: .normal)
            i += 1
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        makeStack()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func makeStack() {
        let buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4]
        for btn in buttons {
            btn.backgroundColor = .gray
            btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)
            btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 10
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        stackView.frame = bounds
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var viewone = UIView()
    var viewtwo = UIView()
    var viewthree = UIView()
    var viewfour = UIView()
    var container = UIView()
    var stackView = UIStackView()
    var buttonRow = ButtonRow()
    var currentView = UIView()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        self.view = view
        setupStack()
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        print("will layout subviews")
        //autolayout the stack view
        let hSpacing: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/8
        let wSpacing: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/10
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor, constant: -wSpacing).isActive = true
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor, constant: wSpacing).isActive = true
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: hSpacing).isActive = true
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor, constant: -hSpacing).isActive = true

        }
        else {
            let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: -wSpacing).isActive = true
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: wSpacing).isActive = true
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: hSpacing).isActive = true
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: -hSpacing).isActive = true
        }
    }

    func setupContainer() {
        container.backgroundColor = .yellow
        viewone.backgroundColor = .blue
        viewtwo.backgroundColor = .red
        viewthree.backgroundColor = .green
        viewfour.backgroundColor = .black
        for vl in [viewone, viewtwo, viewthree, viewfour] as [UIView]  {
            container.addSubview(vl)
            vl.isHidden = true
            vl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive = true
            vl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            vl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
            vl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
            vl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        currentView = viewone
        viewone.isHidden = false
    }

    func setupButtons() {
        buttonRow.updateButtonLabels()
        var i = 1
        for btn in [buttonRow.button1, buttonRow.button2, buttonRow.button3, buttonRow.button4] {
            btn.tag = i
            btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewChange), for: .touchUpInside)
            i += 1
        }

    }

    func setupStack() {
        setupButtons()
        setupContainer()
        stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [container, buttonRow])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 10
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // add some component constraints
        let bHeight = buttonRow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        stackView.addConstraints([bHeight])

        view.addSubview(stackView)
    }

    // MARK: - Methods
    @objc func viewChange(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.tag)
        switch sender.tag {
        case 1 :
            print("should look at view1")
            print(currentView)
            UIView.transition(from: self.currentView, to: self.viewone, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
            currentView = viewone
            viewone.isHidden = false
            viewtwo.isHidden = true
            viewthree.isHidden = true
            viewfour.isHidden = true
        case 2 :
            print(currentView)
            UIView.transition(from: self.currentView, to: self.viewtwo, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
            currentView = viewtwo
            viewone.isHidden = true
            viewtwo.isHidden = false
            viewthree.isHidden = true
            viewfour.isHidden = true
        case 3 :
            print(currentView)
            UIView.transition(from: self.currentView, to: self.viewthree, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
            currentView = viewthree
            viewone.isHidden = true
            viewtwo.isHidden = true
            viewthree.isHidden = false
            viewfour.isHidden = true
        case 4 :
            print(currentView)
            UIView.transition(from: self.currentView, to: self.viewfour, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, completion: nil)
            currentView = viewfour
            viewone.isHidden = true
            viewtwo.isHidden = true
            viewthree.isHidden = true
            viewfour.isHidden = false
        default:
            currentView = viewone
            viewone.isHidden = false
            viewtwo.isHidden = true
            viewthree.isHidden = true
            viewfour.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

The print statements show that there is still a **currentview** identified, but that it's frame changes from "frame = (0 0; 221 416)" to "frame = (-77 -96; 0 0)":

```
will layout subviews
will layout subviews
1
should look at view1
<UIView: 0x7f7f42100630; frame = (0 0; 221 416); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000221440>>
2
<UIView: 0x7f7f42100630; frame = (0 0; 221 416); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000221440>>
3
<UIView: 0x7f7f421031f0; frame = (0 0; 221 416); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000221340>>
4
<UIView: 0x7f7f421033d0; frame = (0 0; 221 416); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000220140>>
1
should look at view1
<UIView: 0x7f7f421035b0; frame = (0 0; 221 416); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000220de0>>
2
<UIView: 0x7f7f42100630; frame = (-77 -96; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000221440>>
3
<UIView: 0x7f7f421031f0; frame = (-77 -96; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000221340>>
4
<UIView: 0x7f7f421033d0; frame = (-77 -96; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000220140>>
```

NOTE: I created a video, but I cannot seem to upload it to SO or my Gist.

I don't understand why the frame changes. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I think that every time you call `constraint` on a `NSLayoutAnchor`, you create a new constraint so I wouldn't be surprised that after 2 iterations, UIKit cannot solve the constraints any more.

You should try to add a symbolic breakpoint for `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` and see if that's your issue.

Comment: I was not able to add a symbolic breakpoint in the playground (it's all greyed out). Also, it shouldn't have a constraint issue because the subviews `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. However, your comment gave me an idea, and I explicitly set the frame in the completion block of the animation, and now it works. I still don't really know WHY without more detailed debug.